# I have got a mouse offset in VMWare VSphere Client when I click on the desktop

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vsphere

Hello everyone and sorry for my mistakes,

I am new with the virtual machine and I have to work on it. To do so, my school forced me to work on VMWare VSphere Client. The version I am currently using is the 5.5.

My problem is that when I do a right on the desktop, there is an offset between the mouse and the menu. I tried to unistall and reinstall it, but this problem always appears. I also tried to tun it with the Windows 7 compatibility and the others compatibility.

[My problem : Offset between the mouse and the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7A04.png)

I know that this problem is due to my computer because the same version of VMWare VSpere Client works perfectly on similar computers but not on mine.

My computer config :
ASUS K501UW
RAM 8Go
64 Bits
Intel Core i7

Tank you by advance for yours helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is really very late, but perhaps this helps others. I had the mouse click problem with Windows 10 and viclient 5.5 too. This was because I was using custom display scaling in Windows 10. I changed to de-select the option "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" and then the mouse clicks worked again in viclient. I did not have to disable custom scaling.